# How to configure the Devart LinqConnect Database Context with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, database, dependency-injection, database-connection, devart

I have a Library project that I store all business logic for a Backend API service. Included in that library is the Database Context provided by Devart. How can I setup a Transient Service in my Startup.cs that will allow me to specify the connection string that I want to use when c# initiates the database with Dependency Injection? Here is some code with what I'm looking at and some of what I have tried.

I know that if you have a normal DbContext you can use the following:

```
_ = services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
```

But because this is a devart data context I am not provided the options to do that.

I have tried creating a partial class:

```
public partial class CustomDbContext : Library.DevartDbContext
    {
        public CustomDbContext() : base(dbConnectionString) { }
    }
```

Which this is just overriding the default Devart Db Context constructor, and this works, only If I am using the CustomDbContext class in my library, which I am not.

Here is what the line looks like where I am injecting my DbContext currently and relying on the connection string to come from the library.

```cs
_ = services.AddTransient<Library.DevartDbContext>();
```

I have not used Ninject before, would this be a good solution that could handle this for me?

I can get my project to compile If I do this:

```
_ = services.AddTransient(x => new Library.DevartDbContext(dbConnectionString));
```

are there any consequences for setting up my db context like this? - EDIT
Devart does not actually allow me to do this. I get an error with my connection string saying Key is not valid: license key. So I'm back to square 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my solution of using

```cs
_ = services.AddTransient(x => new Library.DevartDbContext(dbConnectionString));
```

was the correct solution, the errors I was getting were not related to using the Devart Data Context this way. Because I had a previous database context that is still in the project and still being used, when I updated the connection string in my startup to point to the devart one that contains a license key in it, that's where my errors were coming from.

For the time being I now just supply two different connection strings, one with the license key and one without to be used with the selective database contexts.